# Update a local repo with Git (Bitbucket)

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I switched recently to a Bitbucket/git system to work on my code, and i'm having some troubles understanding.

Here what I did:

- Created a repo on Bitbucket, pushed all my code into it, from my computer A.
- On my computer B, I cloned this code and worked on it. I pushed every modifications on Bitbucket.

But now, it may be very simple, but I don't know how I get back my modifications I push (the latest commits) on my computer A...

I tried forking as written on the doc, but it's creating another repo... I don't get it :(

Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pull your changes in your local repo on computer A. Run the following (assuming your branch name is master)

```
git pull origin master
```

For a basic guide to git, check out http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/